# Access types of a reference project from another

Tags: typescript, project-reference

I have the following project structure:

```
- /
  - tsconfig.json
  - tsconfig-base.json
  - /src
    - types.ts
    - tsconfig.json
  - /test
    - myTest.ts
    - tsconfig.json
  - /dist
```

`/tsconfig.json` is a solution, it references `/src/tsconfig.json` and `/test/tsconfig.json`.

`/src/tsconfig.json` and `/test/tsconfig.json` both inherit from `/tsconfig-base.json` which contains project-wide `compilerOptions`.

`/test/tsconfig.json` references `/src/tsconfig.json` to get access to the types declared in `/src/types.ts`. These types are visible within `/src` but not from `/test`, as expected. What am I doing wrong?

`/tsconfig.json`

```json
{
    "files": [],
    "include": [],
    "references": [
        { "path": "src" },
        { "path": "test" }
    ]
}
```

`/tsconfig-base.json`

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2020",
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "rootDir": ".",
        "composite": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declarationMap": true
    }
}
```

`/src/tsconfig.json`

```json
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig-base",
    "include": [
        "./*",
        "./**/*"
    ]
}
```

`/test/tsconfig.json`

```json
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig-base",
    "references": [
        { "path": "../src" }
    ],
    "include": [
        "./*",
        "./**/*"
    ]
}
```

`/src/types.ts`

```js
interface Array<T> {
    myTestMethod(): void
}
```

`/test/myTest.ts`

```js
const arr: Array<string> = new Array<string>();
arr.prototype.myTestMethod; // Should be undefined; instead throws "property myTestMethod does not exist [...]"
```

**Update 1**:

If `/test/tsconfig.json` is directly made aware of the `/src/types.ts` *script* (not a module), it seems to work:

```json
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig-base",
    "references": [
        { "path": "../src" }
    ],
    "include": [
        "./*",
        "./**/*",
        "../src/types.ts"
    ]
}
```

This solution however, in my opinion, is quite dirty. By `/test` referencing `/src`, shouldn't the `/src/types.ts` script be visible and run automatically? Isn't it the intended behaviour?